# in_array not working properly in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

`in_array` function is returning 1 if values exists, otherwise it returns an empty string. I am expecting it to return `true` or `false`.
Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Could you tell more how do you use `in_array` function?

Comment: When you echo the result, it will always be 1 or an empty string. Try echoing/logging `get type($result)` to show that it's a boolean.

Comment: @aynber I am logging this using Laravel Logger "Log::info(in_array('2017-01-01',$dates)

Comment: Try `Log::info(gettype(in_array('2017-01-01', $dates)));`. A boolean false always writes out as an empty string.

Comment: Please include the full code sample where you suspect the error happens. Otherwise it is hard to understand what you wanna achieve.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP the integer value 1 is converted to `true`, check out the documentation on booleans in PHP [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).

You could use it as a boolean like so

```
$arrBoolean = in_array("needle", $arr);
if ($arrBoolean) {
    // Code
}
```

If you want it to say `true` or `false` you could do this

```
$arrBoolean = in_array("needle", $arr) ? 'True' : 'False';
echo($arrBoolean);
```

However, if you do that, then they are String representations of a boolean and do not actually work as a boolean, they will be just Strings.

Comment: I did this do {/*some code*/}while(in_array('2017-01-01',$dates)). But didn't work , don't know what i am missing

Comment: Add a semi colon to the end of your while loop like `do {/*some code*/}while(in_array('2017-01-01',$dates));` or do something like this `while (in_array('2017-01-01', $dates)) {
    # code...
  }`

Comment: are you telling me that in_array() works differently for while and do while loop. Strange !!!

Comment: No I am not trying to say that, sorry if it came out that way